# How can I get Nginx to listen on all host names instead of specific ones?

Tags: nginx

This is a part of my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. (I've modified it here slightly as to not disclose the actual IP address or DNS entry, but you get the idea.)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-52-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://thumbor;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.1.2.3;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://thumbor;
    }
}
```

I've also got an `upstream` section for thumbor, based on [this guide](http://blog.paulrugelhiatt.com/ec2/thumbor/2014/10/26/image-processing-with-thumbor-behind-nginx-on-ec2.html). And this works; I can access it via http://ec2-52-1-2-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com/... or via http://52.1.2.3/...

However I feel that it's a little bit fragile the way it's set up right now. What if the IP address changes? Or what if the DNS entry changes? I would prefer if it would simply respond to all requests on port 80, regardless of the hostname.

So naturally I tried doing this instead:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://thumbor;
    }
}
```

As you can see all I did there was pare it down to a single `server` section instead of two, and I removed the `server_name` variable from that section. But rather than responding to all requests like I hoped, it no longer responded to any. It would 404 on everything.

How can I set up a generic server listener like I'm describing here?

Answer (score 2):

No need for regular expressions. You can do it by appending `default_server` to your listen directive, like so: `listen 80 default_server;`. This points to the configuration which is to be applied if a request is directed at server IP but no hostname is matching.

Comment: I left this question open because I was hoping someone would come along just like this and show me a better way! Thank you. However... I think I'm still missing something. I removed the `server_name` variable altogether and added `default_server` to the listen just as you instructed. But then when I tried running `sudo service nginx restart` it said `[ fail ]`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Leave the `server_name` directive in place - it's required and doesn't interfere with `default_server`. You can test nginx configuration with `nginx -t` before attempting a restart. The output may be helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Wait... I figured it out, after realizing that you can use regular expressions. I ended up doing this as my single `server` section:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^.+$;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://thumbor;
    }
}
```